# Only part of CSS is active

Tags: javascript, css

I need some help. For a school assignment, I'm supposed to highlight the row of a table which the user's mouse cursor is hovering over. I know you can easily do this with CSS, but the teacher specifically stated he wants it done with Javascript. Anyway, I have it done for the most part. The row is highlighted, but there is a slight problem.

The problem I'm running into is when the mouse hovers over a table row, the only part of my .highlight rule in my css that works is the background-color rule. My color rule is being ignored. I want the background to be black and the text to be red. A little further clarification, as it stands right now, when the mouse hovers over a table row, the background color is changing (from light blue to black) and the text color stays the same (dark blue). It never changes to red like it should. It's probably something really small and dumb that I'm missing. Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

My javascript code:

```
function highlightRows(){

  var rows;    
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  var numTables = tables.length;
  var before;

   for(var x = 0; x < numTables; x++){
    if(tables[x].getAttribute("class") == "stripe_table"){

      rows = tables[x].getElementsByTagName("tr");

      var numRows = rows.length;
      for (var i=1; i < numRows; i++){

        var j= i;
        var k= i+1;   

        rows[j].onmouseover=function(){
          before = this.className;
          this.className = "highlight";

          this.onmouseout = function(){
            this.className = before;
          };
        };

        rows[k].onmouseover=function(){
          before = this.className;
          this.className = "highlight";

          this.onmouseout = function(){
            this.className =  before;
          };
        };

        if(i == rows.length - 2)
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My CSS:

```
table{ 
    width:800px; 
    border: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
caption{
    font-weight: bold;
}
tr > th{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
}
td{
    color: darkblue;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
tbody{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.orange{
    background-color: orange;
}
.highlight{
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: can you provide your html also?

Comment: I would, but Teemu figured it out. Thanks for taking a stab at it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, because the color rule for `td` overrides the rule for `tr` in your CSS. A quikc-fix would be to move `color: darkblue;` to rule for `tr`.

Comment: That was it. I knew it had to be some sort of color rule override issue. I don't know why I didn't think of just making a `tr` rule and putting dark blue in there. Thank you for the help!